# Profile image is not displayed (error 403)

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I'm using Google API (People) list and from returned JSON, I try to use image listed on "url" field:

```
     "photos": [
    {
      "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/cm/AATWAfu9TeDbEEC2VEJqYuO1eGr1F7qRpGSvgKlsjMhny8UWSAB_STRGbHQYvwIQzgrp=s100", 
      "default": true, 
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT", 
          "id": "4da7eb9a8d9a19e5"
        }, 
        "primary": true
      }
    }
  ]
```

Problem is - not all images are displayed, like you can see here:
https://i.postimg.cc/BvPJLyD5/image-2023-01-11-172253699.png.
On console, I see error 403.
When I manually copy link (from "url" link above) and open it in browser, image is normally displayed. Also, when I reload page few times manually, some images are displayed and some other not (randomly).
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What's the full error message and where are you trying to display these images?

Comment: here is error message: https://i.postimg.cc/3rtSqPVB/image-2023-01-12-072216250.png
here is bad response: https://i.postimg.cc/gj7K0PPb/image-2023-01-12-072326413.png
and here is OK response: https://i.postimg.cc/ncQ41gJM/image-2023-01-12-072413966.png
Thank you for your help

Comment: I try to display images inside Framework7 ListView (https://framework7.io/kitchen-sink/core/?theme=aurora)

Comment: @Daniel, do you have any idea why is that happening?

Comment: What about the "Response" tab? My guess is that it's something [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) related, where the images are not allowed to be embedded under a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to logged status.
If I'm logged into Gmail or Drive, images are randomly displayed.
If I logout from Gmail and use API again, all images are always displayed. It is same for Google Drive, as you can see here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229184403?pli=1

Comment: Ahhh... it worked for few times and now it displays 403 error again. I do not show images on People API, now I try to use thumbnail links from Drive. It means, I'm not logged any more in Google (using logout link: https://accounts.google.com/logout) and thumbnails are only partially displayed, each time different thumbnails are displayed and other are not. Please help.